# How can I store or obtain the inaccurate route that was searched for?

Tags: node.js, express, backend

[In this case, how could I save the /india route in a variable in the router? `app.get(‘*’, function(req, res){ //Save rute here; }`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIDgT.png)

Comment: What do you mean "store it in a variable in the router".  You can create a wildcard handler (after all your routes) that ALL routes that aren't matched will hit and you can then save that path to whatever data store you want.  It's not clear what you're asking here?

Comment: I need to know which route was searched for because I want to keep a record of what my clients search for inaccurately. I don't know how to save it

Comment: @jfriend00 I need to know which route was searched for because I want to keep a record of what my clients search for inaccurately. I don't know how to save it

Comment: @jfriend00 I keep in the Logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to log the bad route to a file, you can do something like this.  Just make this is the last route you define so that all other routes get a chance to match before it does:

```
app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    // log the unhandled route
    fs.appendFile("bad-routes.txt", req.path + "\n", (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(`Error attempting to append ${req.path} to bad-routes.txt`);
        }
    });
    res.sendStatus(404);
});
```

Note, in this list, you will probably find things that crawlers (not users) are also probing your site for.

The above logs only GET requests.  If you want to log for all http verbs, you could do this:

```
app.use((req, res) => {
    // log the unhandled route
    fs.appendFile("bad-routes.txt", `${req.method}: ${req.path}\n`, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(`Error attempting to append ${req.path} to bad-routes.txt`);
        }
    });
    res.sendStatus(404);
});
```

---

It's possible that `fs.appendFile()` could have some race conditions if multiple requests were both trying to log.  In that case, it would be safer to use a shared stream which will safely sequence the writes:

```
let logUnhandledStream;

app.use((req, res) => {
    // log the unhandled route
    if (!logUnhandledStream) {
        logUnhandledStream = fs.createWriteStream("bad-routes.txt", { flags: "a" });
        logUnhandledStream.on('error', err => {
            console.log(`Error attempting to log to bad-routes.txt`, err);
        });
    }
    logUnhandledStream.write(`${req.method}: ${req.path}\n`);
    res.sendStatus(404);
});
```

Comment: @diegocast - Please see my update at the end for a concurrency-safer way to do this.  This shared stream will also perform better (though hopefully this isn't getting called a lot).